# Strong access control for Gollum?

Tags: git, wiki, gollum-wiki

What is the best way to add multiple role access to a Gollum wiki?

I understand how to add Basic HTTP auth via, Rack middleware. However, I would like to know what's required to have full multi user/role authentication and authorization.

Can Devise or OmniAuth be used in a similar way to a Rails app?

What is required?

Comment: @ChrisF I'm going to reword this to make it on topic. +vote to re-open.

Comment: Until it's reopened, I suggest anyone driving by should consider wrapping Gollum inside a Rails app as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372435/311660 - wrapping different levels of authorization (e.g. with CanCan etc.) may require forking Gollum to do so, it depends on the granularity of authorization/roles/rights desired.

Answer (score 17):

With this hint http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auth my configuration file  like this

```
# authentication.rb
module Precious
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
      [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
    end
  end
end
```

and running as:

```
$ gollum --config authentication.rb
```

In the running gollum instance, it will ask for user name and password

Answer (score 6):

There's also the omnigollum project (https://github.com/arr2036/omnigollum) to support omniauth with gollum.

Answer (score 2):

I found a basic http-auth extension here: https://gist.github.com/2224709

Comment: That's the best option so far but it doesn't allow hierarchical control.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here for anyone interested: Using vigntom's method, I made a repo with basic auth added in for Gollum, ready to go. I put credentials in a yaml file to keep them from being hard coded in the repo.

https://github.com/mrchameleon/precious

Answer (score 0):

In this thread

https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/107

one of the Gollum developers gives some hints. No known fork / project yet it seems.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.