# How to properly mount github's gollum wiki inside a Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rack, gollum-wiki

I'm trying to provide a gollum based wiki for my app by mounting it as a rack application inside my routes.rb file:

```
require 'gollum/frontend/app'

#Gollun config

gollum_path = Rails.root
Precious::App.set(:gollum_path, gollum_path)
Precious::App.set(:wiki_options, {:universal_toc => false})

TestWiki::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Precious::App, :at => "wiki"
end
```

The wiki is supposed to run at '/wiki' but everytime a go to this url it redirects me to `/wiki/create/Home`, and after a create a page it redirects me to `/wiki/wiki/page_name`.
Am I missing some option? is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll share with you what I did to get it working just now.  I actually started with your code above and tweaked it until I got it sorted.  If you're still hacking on it, maybe it'll work for you.

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'gollum'
```

In routes.rb:

```
require 'gollum/app'

YourApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  Precious::App.set(:gollum_path, Rails.root.join('wiki').to_s)
  Precious::App.set(:default_markup, :markdown) # set your favorite markup language
  Precious::App.set(:wiki_options, {:universal_toc => false})
  mount Precious::App, at: 'wiki'
end
```

Then, and this is the most important part, create and initialize the wiki directory:

```
~/Sites/ams$ mkdir wiki
~/Sites/ams$ cd wiki
~/Sites/ams/wiki$ ls
~/Sites/ams/wiki$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/xxx/Sites/ams/wiki/.git/
```

Shut down the server, `bundle install`, restart the server, and hit /wiki.

Good Luck.

Edit 2014-11-06: The latest release of gollum has a slightly different directory structure than at the time of the original writing. I've updated the routes.rb sample to match the latest gollum and rails.

Comment: Any suggestions for how this could work will multiple wikis? e.g. wiki/1, wiki/2

Comment: I'd suggest sticking the `Precious::App` and `require` lines in `config/initializers/gollum.rb`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Breaks with the error `bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
`

Comment: @Anurag, do not copy `Ams::Application.routes.draw`, put all `Precious::App` inside your `YourApp::Application.routes.draw`. Anyway in current version require path must be fixed `require 'gollum/app'`.

Comment: I've update the code sample above to match a little better. Hopefully it clears up any confusion.

Comment: Excuse me, what does `Precious::App` do? I didn't find it in API doc. It's neither on middleware list.

Comment: @knh170 Precious::App is the internal sinatra rack application that serves Gollum. see: https://github.com/gollum/gollum/blob/master/lib/gollum/app.rb#L48  and  https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki/Gollum-via-Rack

Comment: @voxobscuro thanks, yet another question: did anyone spot unexpected behaviors after mount gollum to `/wiki`?Run it at `/` root works just fine. As I found problems doing so: https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/1121

Comment: this doesn't work for Rails 5 unfortunately
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@hspace/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:579:in `unshift': can't modify frozen Array (RuntimeError)

Comment: The not yet released 5.x branch seems to work with Rails 5.2. Change the gemfile to pull the repo from github until release: `gem 'gollum', github: 'gollum/gollum', branch: '5.x'`

Comment: Would like to add that this doesn't quite work out of the box anymore and a `bundle update` is required (I believe specifically to update the version of RubyPython). Just had me stuck for a bit, thought I'd share with anyone else trying