# Rails/Gollum: Gollum does not use path prefix to load assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I mount gollum inside my Rails app like provided [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053704/how-to-properly-mount-githubs-gollum-wiki-inside-a-rails-app)
It works, however the CSS and Javascript assets do not load properly.

`routes.rb`:

```
authenticate :user do
    mount Precious::App, at: 'wiki'
end
```

So I can access the wiki at `/wiki`. This works, but gollum tries to load the css files from eg. `http://localhost:3000/css/gollum.css` which does not work, instead of `http://localhost:3000/wiki/css/gollum.css`. How do I tell gollum to use the correct prefix?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a bug in either Rails or Gollum.  I know that Gollum does have the ability to map its assets to a subpath, because I do it in my apps (via Rack, though, not Rails routes), like this:

```
map "/wiki" do
  run Precious::App
end
```

Reporting a bug would probably be your best bet.