# How to properly mount github's gollum wiki inside a Rails 4 App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wiki

I am trying to create a rails app with a wiki,I was wondering if anyone know how to **mount a wiki to rails 4**.

All the answers I am seeing seem to be out of date [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053704/how-to-properly-mount-githubs-gollum-wiki-inside-a-rails-app)

gives me an **error**.

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH.  This has caused me great frustration.
```